# Suggesting a chemistry homework site

Tags: discussion, scope, homework, area51

I think there a should be separate site for homework, where students can show their efforts and post their questions.

Many questions of that type are closed here for unnecessary reasons.

Comment: Firstly, if you think you want to create a new platform for Chem HW questions, then go to Area 51 and propose a site based on that. That being said, I really don't think, it would get a minimal amount of activity. SE is not a platform for questions which remain too localised i.e. helpful to only a few users.At the past, numerous efforts were made to create _Physics Underflow_ for HW queries; but no one succeeded. SE is really not meant for such things. And moreover, we have no problem with HWs that ask a specific conceptual query showing some effort to work through the problem. Think on that.

Comment: "where students can show their effort" Your question has the chance of getting answered here already if it shows effort even if it's homework.

Comment: @M.A.R. No, it doesn't get answered here even after effort is shown. It gets answered in Physics.SE and Math.SE but not Chem.SE.

Answer (score 9):

The Stack Exchange way to propose new sites is to head over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and start a proposal there. It will have to make its way through three phases: Definition, commitment and private beta before it becomes open to the general public. Everything else you need to know about the process is highlighted in the [FAQ of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

However, your chances for successfully starting such a proposal are not great. Stack Exchange wishes its sites to be designed primarily for experts. Answering homework-type questions typically becomes rather boring rather quickly to those that know what they are doing. Another reason why such a site is likely to fail is the fact that typically the questions are asked once, answered once and then never needed again, hence not a lot of reputation is to be gained from them. And finally, it would take a Stack Exchange experienced starting user base and not just the people on the interwebs who want their homework solved.

Now finally, chemistry.stackexchange.com **does** allow homework questions **if** they are well-written, thought through and the OP has done work by themselves and is just getting stuck at a certain point (the work has to be shown in the question). This has something to do with the point of homework: It is supposed to help you learn. However, entering the exact quote into a Google search bar and/or pasting it into a random internet site, waiting a few hours and then copying the answer into one’s exercise book is not going to make one learn anything aside from copypasting. You need to understand the question, understand what it wants you to do and then attempt a solution. If that failed, you are welcome here. If that didn’t happen, well …